Color the bonds of a cycle
I would like to be able to put the bonds of a cycle in the same color.
Is there a solution while keeping the syntax of a cycle (\chemfig{*6(------)} ?
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(------)}
\end{document}


The color can be specified with the key bond style.
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig[bond style=cyan]{*6(------)}
\end{document}


